# How to customize python logger behavior?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, stdout

I have implemented a custom_logger that my other python classes uses.

```
import logging, sys

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d %(levelname)-8s [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s',
    datefmt='%d-%m-%Y:%H:%M:%S',

logger = logging.getLogger()
```

I'm going to use it as follows:

```
import custom_logger as cl
cl.logger.debug('Extracting locations and descriptors from %s' % image_path)
```

I'm running my python files from a script in which I'm trying to redirect the logging in a different files for sout and serr

```
nohup python3  "$CLASSPATH""$MAIN_CLASS" $MAIN_CLASS_ARGUMENT 1>>$SOUT_FILE 2>>$SERR_FILE & echo $! > $PID_FILE
```

With the current setup, I get every log in the .err file

> 17-12-2018:17:56:59,203 INFO     [conn.py:1008] Set configuration
>   api_version=(0, 11, 0) to skip auto check_version requests on startup
>   17-12-2018:17:56:59,206 INFO     [subscription_state.py:172] Updating
>   subscribed topics to: ('PROCESSED_SCENES',) 17-12-2018:17:56:59,209
>   INFO     [cluster.py:342] Group coordinator for my_group is
>   BrokerMetadata(nodeId=0, host='172.1.1.3', port=9094, rack=None)

I tried tweaking the logger to output the error in each file, with no success:

```
import logging, sys

class StdErrFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, rec):
        return rec.levelno in (logging.ERROR, logging.WARNING)

class StdOutFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, rec):
        return rec.levelno in (logging.DEBUG, logging.INFO)

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d %(levelname)-8s [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s',
    datefmt='%d-%m-%Y:%H:%M:%S',
    level=logging.INFO)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d %(levelname)-8s [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s','%d-%m-%Y:%H:%M:%S')

logger = logging.getLogger()


h1 = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
h1.setFormatter(formatter)
h1.addFilter(StdOutFilter())
logger.addHandler(h1)

h2 = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr)
h2.setFormatter(formatter)
h2.addFilter(StdErrFilter())
logger.addHandler(h2)
```

All I'm getting now is having the same output in both .err .out files.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`basicConfig` configures a handler, so you have `h1`, `h2` and basic logging. Maybe this causes confusion? Also you need to do `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` for the logger to process the debug level at all.

Removing `basicConfig` and adding `setLevel` seems to work as intended:

```
import logging, sys

class StdErrFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, rec):
        return rec.levelno in (logging.ERROR, logging.WARNING)

class StdOutFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, rec):
        return rec.levelno in (logging.DEBUG, logging.INFO)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d %(levelname)-8s [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s','%d-%m-%Y:%H:%M:%S')
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

h1 = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
h1.setFormatter(formatter)
h1.addFilter(StdOutFilter())
logger.addHandler(h1)

h2 = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr)
h2.setFormatter(formatter)
h2.addFilter(StdErrFilter())
logger.addHandler(h2)

logger.info('stdout log')
logger.error('stderr log')
```